# Sort Column by Specific Row

Tags: vba, sorting

I would like to sort Columns E though "lastColumn" in ascending order. 
The values to be used for sorting are in Row 14.
The data set is located in cells E8 to "lastColumn" "lastRow".

Below is what I have thus far, but I am getting an error that the reference is not valid. I'm guessing I am not using &lastRow& correctly, let alone trying to plug in the value for "lastColumn".

I am using lastColumn and lastRow as a means to ignore blank cells.

```
Sub SortColumns()

Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "E14:Z" & lastRow&), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("E8:I" & lastRow)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only had a small mistake. I added a little more code as you should always be specific on which workbook and on which sheet you are working. Try this:

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
Sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

lastColumn = Sht1.Cells(8, Sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = Sht1.Cells(Sht1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sht1.Sort.SortFields.Clear

Sht1.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "E14:Z" & lastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With Sht1.Sort
    .SetRange Range("E8:I" & lastRow)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Hi Kathara, thank you for your assistance on this.

I am getting an error in defining sht1. The sheet I am referencing is titled 'Template' and ultimately, I will need this to run on which ever sheet is active.

The Error is Run-time error '91'
Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: I should mention that the active sheet is already defined in my macro as ws. 

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = ActiveSheet